# Entity Framework 4 Stored Procedure Call Timing Out

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure imported into EF4, and when I call it with certain parameters after 30 seconds it throws a time out error. In SQL Server profiler I can see the stored procedure call with the proper parameters taking just over 30 seconds, which is the timeout on my application.

HOWEVER when I execute the same SQL sent to the profiler in Query Analyzer it executes sub-second. What could cause this discrepancy between being called from EF and being called from SQL Server Management Studio?

Full stack trace of .NET error bellow.

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) +2073486
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064444
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2275
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +86
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +311
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) +987
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +32
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +141
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +12
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   +10    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +443
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing
>   the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +479
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateFunctionObjectResult(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, EntitySet entitySet, EdmType edmType, MergeOption
>   mergeOption) +182
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String functionName,
>   MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters) +218
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String functionName,
>   ObjectParameter[] parameters) +53
>   MetaView.DAL.MFCMData.MFCMDATAEntities.GetTradingOpenPositionCounterParty(Nullable`1
>   positionDT, Nullable`1 tradingAccountID) in
>   C:\Projects\CASH\web\MetaView\MetaView.DAL.MFCMData\MFCMData.Designer.cs:7064
>   MetaView.BusinessLayer.Shared.Accounts.CounterParties.GetCounterParties(Int32
>   tradingAccountID) in
>   C:\Projects\CASH\web\MetaView\MetaView.BusinessLayer\Shared\Accounts\CounterParties.cs:161

Comment: Please post the query and both execution plans.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I had a similar issue a couple of weeks ago, which was explained to me by one of our DBAs thusly (paraphrased and dumbed down to my level of course):

When a SQL Server stored procedure is called, the server creates and caches an execution plan per stored procedure *per `object_id`*. Sometimes a bad execution plan can be created by SQL Server depending on the parameter value that is passed in (in our case it was null for a nullable parameter). When this happens, the quick fix is to run `sp_recompile 'Schema.Procedure'` in SQL Server Management Studio (or whatever DB management tool you might be using). All this does is clear the plan cache for that stored procedure. If the next callee of the proc passes in the "bad" parameter value again you'll be stuck in the same situation **so the real fix is to** give the query a hint using the `OPTIMIZE FOR` syntax (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181714.aspx).

In short if you add `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@myParameter = 'Some value that gives you a GOOD execution plan'))` after your `WHERE` and/or `ORDER BY` clauses it should fix the issue.

Also, if you're wondering why when executing the *same* SQL in SSMS you always get fast results it's because SSMS has a default setting of ON for an option called ARITHABORT (`SET ARITHABORT ON`) which all other apps have set to OFF by default, but how it works and its implications are beyond my experience and I haven't bothered to read up on it. I have been told that I shouldn't use it though. I'm sure a real DBA can do a better job of explaining why.

Comment: Re: **the server creates and caches an execution plan per stored procedure per calling application (or per connection string. I don't remember correctly).** Actually, it is neither. The plan is cached per `object_id`, and in the case of ad hoc sql, the `object_id` is based on a hash of the query text (assuming a binary comparison of all characters).

Comment: I have exaclty the same problem with a FUNCTION (with AS TABLE) but OPTION (OPTIMIZE...) don't seem to work in this context. Do you have any idea to resolve my issue ?

Comment: I have found a solution here : http://geekswithblogs.net/mknapp/archive/2011/12/09/mysterious-query-timeouts.aspx It was a problem with statistics query plan. You have to set "Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously" to TRUE in your Database Properties

Comment: Thanks toregua, I think your answer is more appropriate and should not be just a comment.  The other answer, though technically interesting, may not fit my needs. My stored proc's query cannot have a static value that would work -- I'd have a messed up application state if I left records around to fit that need. One of the OPTIMIZE FOR... keywords is UNKNOWN, but that seems like the default, and wouldn't change much.