# asp.net entity framework stored procedure error on second stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In ASP.NET MVC I have this controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using test.DB;
using test.EFView;

namespace test.Controllers
{
    public class OrderAndDDTController : Controller
    {

        // GET: OrderAndDDT
        public ActionResult Index(DateTime? Start, DateTime? End)
        {
            if (Start != null && End != null)
            {
                using (var db = new PROVA_ETLEntities())
                {
                    ViewBag.Start = Start;
                    ViewBag.End = End;
                    var list = db.ddsp_getFamQty_FI(Start, End).OrderBy(x => x.Famiglia).ToList();
                    return View(list);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Customer(DateTime? Start, DateTime? End, string Famiglia)
        {
            if (Start != null && End != null)
            {
                using (var db = new PROVA_ETLEntities())
                {
                    ViewBag.Start = Start;
                    ViewBag.End = End;
                    ViewBag.Famiglia = Famiglia;
                    var list = db.ddsp_getFamCustQty_FI(Start, End, Famiglia).OrderBy(x => x.Cliente).ToList();
                    return View(list);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Index view I have a button that run the second `actionresult`, "Customer". When I try to run it, it goes in timeout. I try the same stored procedure with the parameters that the code above will pass, and it takes less then one second to execute. It seems that the first SQL statement remain opening and will not allow to send the second (I see it in SQL Activity Monitor).

The point that goes in error it's the autogenerate code (By Entity Framework) and is this

```
public virtual ObjectResult<ddsp_getFamCustQty_Result> ddsp_getFamCustQty_FI(Nullable<System.DateTime> dateStart, Nullable<System.DateTime> dateEnd, string family)
{
    var dateStartParameter = dateStart.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("dateStart", dateStart) :
        new ObjectParameter("dateStart", typeof(System.DateTime));

    var dateEndParameter = dateEnd.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("dateEnd", dateEnd) :
        new ObjectParameter("dateEnd", typeof(System.DateTime));

    var familyParameter = family != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("family", family) :
        new ObjectParameter("family", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ddsp_getFamCustQty_Result>("ddsp_getFamCustQty_FI", dateStartParameter, dateEndParameter, familyParameter);
}
```

on the last row, with SQL timeout exception.

Comment: I assumed that `ddsp_getFamCustQty_FI` is the SP you want to execute, probably you should try either optimizing the execution plan or increase timeout limit by looking for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772252/entity-framework-4-stored-procedure-call-timing-out.

Comment: Thank you, but was not a problem of time execution (Like I wrote the stored procedure execution was less than one second). At the and I restart the SQL service and now it goes. But thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can set the command timeout as shown below

```
   ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;//in seconds
```

Comment: Thank you, but was not a problem of time execution (Like I wrote the stored procedure execution was less than one second). At the and I restart the SQL service and now it goes. But thank you for the answer